# Is there a way to use knockout binding attr and submit to a single form

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I need to apply bindings to a form and add implement submit binding to a single form.
This is code I have, but the previous bindings are not applied.

```
 <form data-bind= "attr: { 'id': 'form-' + ($index() + 1) }, submit: $root.updateStore">
    ..
 </form>
```

Is the syntax gone wrong? Iam stuck with this guys. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your main question straight up: your syntax hasn't gone wrong, it's just fine.

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "the previous bindings are not applied", and the code you posted isn't enough to reproduce the issue. It may help to include more code in your question, help us reproduce the issue.

If you want to see your own code in action, have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/QTzge/1/). There I've assumed the following full View:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: myForms -->
<form data-bind= "attr: { 'id': 'form-' + ($index() + 1) }, submit: $root.updateStore">
    Form with id 
    '<span data-bind="text: 'form-' + ($index() + 1)"></span>'
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
<!-- /ko -->
```

With the following ViewModels:

```
function form() { }

function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.myForms = ko.observableArray([new form(), new form()]);
    self.updateStore = function(formElement) { alert('submitting ' + formElement.id); };
}
```

You can see the View has a span showing that `id` in a span as well. If you inspect the forms in the fiddle in a developer toolbar you can see that the IDs are bound just fine.